# Ruby - undefined method `deep_transform_keys' for Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When I'm trying to update the Network security group rules for Azure, I get the following error.

`undefined method 'deep_transform_keys' for Array`

Any idea why and how it can be resolved?

```
network_sg = Azure::Armrest::Network::NetworkSecurityGroupService.new(conf)  
network_sg.update('sg_testing_temp_1', 'cloud-shell-storage', network_sg_properties)


[----] E, [2022-07-17T16:36:12.489747 #32747:2ad3b3e0be04] ERROR -- automation: Q-task_id([r988_miq_provision_2589]) <AEMethod azure_sg_provision> The following error occurred during method evaluation:
[----] E, [2022-07-17T16:36:12.501593 #32747:2ad3b3e0be04] ERROR -- automation: Q-task_id([r988_miq_provision_2589]) <AEMethod azure_sg_provision>   NoMethodError: undefined method `deep_transform_keys' for #<Array:0x0000562e6b8e9898>
[----] E, [2022-07-17T16:36:12.503179 #32747:2ad3b3e0be04] ERROR -- automation: Q-task_id([r988_miq_provision_2589]) <AEMethod azure_sg_provision>   /opt/manageiq/manageiq-gemset/gems/azure-armrest-0.14.0/lib/azure/armrest/resource_group_based_service.rb:199:in `transform_create_options'
[----] E, [2022-07-17T16:36:12.507115 #32747:2ad3b3e0601c] ERROR -- automation: Method STDERR: from /ManageIQ_Custom/Cloud/VM/Provisioning/StateMachines/Methods/Azure_SG_Provision:268:in `<main>'
[----] I, [2022-07-17T16:36:12.534925 #32747:2ad3a008b968]  INFO -- automation: Q-task_id([r988_miq_provision_2589]) <AEMethod [/ManageIQ_Custom/Cloud/VM/Provisioning/StateMachines/Methods/Azure_SG_Provision]> Ending
```

Comment: `deep_transform_keys` is a Hash method so you have an Array where the Azure API is expecting a Hash. Maybe start by checking that `conf` and `network_sg_properties` have the right structures.

Comment: the error message even tells you what line (in the Azure code) triggers the error. So you can put a debugger statement there and see what is the cause. If the Azure stuff is from a gem, you will have to run bundle again to reload the gem with your debugger statement.

Answer (score 0):

The options you're providing (`network_sg_properties`) in your call to `update` is an array and should be a hash.